# JSON-like Object Syntax In Java

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, instance

I hate to ask something so trivial, but I can't work this one out.  **I'm trying to create a basic object** for convenience, like this:

```
triangle = {
  side: { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0 },
  angle: { a, b, c },

  function calcAngle(){}
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to just create a generic object on the fly.  I'm only creating one "triangle", must I create a whole class for one instance?  I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but I can't seem to word the question right for anything useful.  For your amusement I'll post some of my failures:

```
public class TGUI{

// Attempt One
   public Object triangle = new Object(){ int test; };
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     triangle.test = 1;
     // ^- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field triangle

     triangle tri = new triangle();
     // ^- Made the compiler cry; triangle cannot be resolved to as type
   }

// Attempt Two
   public class triangle{ int test; }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       triangle tri = new triangle();
       /* ^- No enclosing instance of TGUI is accessible.  Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TGUI (eg x.new A() where x is an instance of TGUI) */
   }

// Attempt Three
   public void triangle(){ int test = 1; }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     triangle tri = new triantle();
     // ^- triangle cannot be resolved to a type
   }

// Attempt Four
   public TGUI(){ int test; }
   /* I'm gonna quit here, you get the idea */
}
```

Comment: Could you just use an array of three `double` values?

Comment: You need to define a Triangle class.  And, generally speaking, it should *not* be nested unless you have a good reason to make it so.

Comment: I could make separate arrays for the sides and the angles, but I like the organization of x.side.a; x.angle.b instead of side[0]; angle[1]; I guess that's the way to go though.  So, the right way to do it is to define a new class in a whole separate file just to use the object once?  Maybe Map is just the way to go.

Comment: You always have the option of leaving it in JSON form.  You lose the "classiness" of being able to invoke methods on it, but the data values remain accessible in a fairly meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 2 was closer. You needed a nested *static* class:

```
public static class triangle{ int test; }
```

(or `triangle` can be in a separate file).

It's still far from how Java operates on its static type system.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, I'd like to just create a generic object on the fly.

Then you shouldn't use a statically typed language.

The only ways to do this in Java are

- use reflection (not what you want), or
- use a JSON library,
- give up typing entirely and use a `Map<String, Integer>.`

In your case, sounds like you just need an actual `Triangle` class though. Java requires lots of typing, better to get used to it than write bad code to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Triangle {
    double sideA;
    double sideB;
    double sideC;
    double[] angles = new double[3];
    double calcAngle() {
        something;
        return somethingElse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

indeed, you should use a JVM-based script language like Groovy to implement such dynamic things out of the box. You would create an instance of `MetaClass` and add all your fields on the fly.
Another option for good ol' Java only would be to create a simple (marker?) interface and implement it as an `anonymous inner class` just where you need it.